# Varnish compilation directory

Tags: debian, varnish

I'm trying to install varnish 4.0 from the official repo on a debian 8 without systemd.
4.1 works fine, but is incompatible so I need to downgrade to 4.0.

When I try /etc/init.d/varnish start :

```
[FAIL] Starting HTTP accelerator: varnishd failed!
Message from C-compiler:
Cannot create temporary file in ./: Permission denied
Running C-compiler failed, signal 6

VCL compilation failed
```

Anyone knows where ./ is ? I tried stracing it and I just can't figure it out. I don't see any path configured in the init script or /etc/default/varnish, doesn't seem to be the user's home either, I just have no idea.
I get this error both with the 4.0 from debian's repo and from varnish's repo.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Apprently

```
chmod 777 /var/lib/varnish/vs1/
```

solves it. That's ugly, but looks like it's not the varnish user trying to access it but the "nobody" user.